# How to resolve compile errors after adding a WCF net tcp service reference in .Net Core Console App targeting .Net 5

Tags: wcf, .net-core, .net-5

After I was able to add a WCF net tcp service reference to my .Net Core Console App targeting .Net 5, under the Dependencies -> Assemblies, System.ServiceModel is listed but has a yellow triangle.

When I checked the Microsoft Docs on this, there was mention it would add needed Nuget packages but non are listed for the project.
[image]

Please advise and thanks for your help,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Find Manage NuGet Packages in the project
[image]

Click Browse, search for System.servicemodel in the search box and install the Nuget package for the project.[image]